# Accessing data from containing view model

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, durandal

You knew it had been quiet for too long, right? ;-)

I have a master viewmodel. Inside the view, I use a compose binding to load a sub view which is "stand alone" as far as what data it displays goes.

```
<div data-bind="compose: articleSection"></div>
```

And "articleSection" is just an observable containing a string:

```
var articleSection = ko.observable('viewmodels/lt_articleRead');
```

...because depending on user actions, I may want a different view/model loaded in that div.

In my master viewmodel I also have an observable "articleSelected":

```
var articleSelected = ko.observable(true);
```

...which is set when an article is selected from list.

Inside my sub view (lt_ArticleRead) I have two divs which can display. One if articleSelected is false and one if true:

```
<div id="articleSelected" data-bind="visible: articleSelected()">
...
</div>
<div id="articleNotSelected" data-bind="visible: articleSelected()">
     <p>Please select an article from the list on the left or create a new one</p>
</div>
```

I've tried using "$root.articleSelected()" and "$parent.articleSelected" to access the observable from the main viewmodel but neither works.  Do I have to "require" the parent viewmodel in the subview for this to work properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `preserveContext:true` on your compose binding.

```
<div data-bind="compose: { model: articleSection, preserveContext: true }"></div>
```

From the [documentation](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition/) (emphasis added by me):

> Whenever a compose happens, an **isolated binding context is created** around that composed view and view model. So, **from inside that view, you cannot reach outside to a different model object**. We believe this is really important for encapsulation because we've seen some really bad architectural things happen when you can "accidentally" reference things outside of the scope. As a result, things are encapsulated by default. If you want, you can **set `preserveContext:true` on the binding to "connect" the new composition to its parent and enable walking up the tree from inside the child composition**, but that is not the default.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I did the `preservecontext=true` bit on the compose binding and tried to access `$parent.articleSelected` but it still said `$parent is not defined` in the console window so I've not got my head around this just yet, sorry!

Comment: @CarlEdwards sorry the syntax of the `preservecontext` was wrong in my answer. Please check now my updated answer!

Comment: I suspect this would work fine but for a problem I've encountered before.  As soon as I specify an object for the compose binding, Durandal decides to go looking in strange places for views & viewmodels and it all breaks.  I'm now getting: `GET http://localhost:5907/App/views/viewmodels/lt_articleRead.html 404 (Not Found)` because it's in `App/views` and not `/App/views/viewmodels` which is where Durandal is looking for some reason!

Comment: Can you try it with `ko.observable('lt_articleRead')` ? So without the `viewmodels`? And by the way which durandal version are you using?

Comment: God I'm such a retard not to see that!  Sorry...  I'm using version 2.0.  I'm now back to the "$parent is not defined" error: `Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: visible: $parent.articleSelected()
Message: $parent is not defined;
View: views/lt_articleRead;
ModuleId: viewmodels/labTool`

Comment: @CarlEdwards Ok so you need to use `model` instead of `view` `<div <data-bind="compose: { model: articleSection, preserveContext: true }"></div>` and you need to change back your `articleSection` to `ko.observable('viewmodels/lt_articleRead');` and the parent will correctly

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks a million, that's really sorted it out. It's so complicated with all the small nuances that you have to know!  Presumably using the model activates the parent somehow whereas using the view doesn't?